# How to get a continuation of the built-in RTC counter after waking up?

Tags: esp8266

The documentation says that the deepsleep timer is designed for approximately 71 minutes and counts in a circle. How to get a continuation of the built-in RTC counter after waking up?
Or does the counter always reset to zero?

If the line is active "ESP.deepSleep((uint32_t)(DEEP_SLEEP_SEC * 1e6))", then the counter is reset every time. If you comment out the line "// ESP.deepSleep((uint32_t)(DEEP_SLEEP_SEC * 1e6))", then the timer continues to count down.

```
#define DEEP_SLEEP_SEC 3
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(74880);
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println(READ_PERI_REG(0x6000071C));
  ESP.deepSleep((uint32_t)(DEEP_SLEEP_SEC * 1e6));
}
```

Comment: for esp8266, deep sleep is a complete off of the MCU except of the internal RTC peripheral. wake-up from deep-sleep is a reset of the MCU.